# Should FindDep.cmake be included for PUBLIC link dependencies without a Config.cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am writing a library `Lib` that has a `PUBLIC` link dependency on `Dep`. Unfortunately, `Dep` does not provide its own `DepConfig.cmake`, so I wrote a `FindDep.cmake` file to find `Dep`.

Currently, I just have `find_dependency(Dep)` in `LibConfig.cmake` and rely on consumers of `Lib` to provide their own `FindDep.cmake`. Ideally though, consumers of `Lib` should be able to `find_package(Lib)` without worrying about `Dep` at all.

I am tempted to install my `FindDep.cmake` to `lib/cmake/Lib`, but I am concerned about the search order of `find_package`. (If the consumer provides their own `FindDep.cmake` or `DepConfig.cmake`, what file is used?).

Is there a best practice for this case?

Comment: `FindDep.cmake` scripts is searched in directories provided by `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable and in that order. `DepConfig.cmake` script would be searched if none `FindDep.cmake` is found. In your `FindDep.cmake` script you may add `find_package(Dep QUIET NO_MODULE)` for try to find `DepConfig.cmake` script.

Comment: Note, that if someone else would write its own `FindDep.cmake` script, and you want to search this script before your own, then that script should be **compatible** with your one in terms of **output** variables or IMPORTED targets. Actually, I see a little reason to use someone's else `FindDep.cmake` script instead of your one. The same is about `DepConfig.cmake` script. So simply add path to your `FindDep.cmake` script at the **beginning** of `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable, (And restore this variable after `find_dependency(Dep)` call).